# Using text files for word search python

Tags: python, text

I want to create a word search generator but I'm finding it a little hard. Ive looked online and found this word search generator which works well but i would like to use my own grid from a text file. Is there way I can code this and place my text file instead of random choice letters.

```
##while True:
##    intext=input('Enter file name: ')
##    
##    if not intext=='grid.txt':
##        print("No such file was found! Enter file name.")
##        continue
##    else:
##
##        break
##grid= open(intext,'r')


import string
import random

width = 12
height = 12

def put_word(word,grid):
    word = random.choice([word,word[::-1]])

    d = random.choice([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
    xsize = width  if d[0] == 0 else width  - len(word)
    ysize = height if d[1] == 0 else height - len(word)

    x = random.randrange(0,xsize)
    y = random.randrange(0,ysize)

    print([x,y])

    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        grid[y + d[1]*i][x + d[0]*i] = word[i]
    return grid

grid = [[random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(0,width)] for j in range(0,height)]

for word in ["HELLO", "THERE", "AGAIN"]:
    grid = put_word(word, grid)

print("\n".join(map(lambda row: " ".join(row), grid))
```

in the grid.txt files are:

```
xmfycxvtljlqbbybkoumjqwbt
caubmeknbeydqmcnzyjpvrank
aqactivexnyvwdvcoshoyaohg
paghzkctudptjdphsztprhttl
sbsnakjwqbouftmgnjqbtlinu
tsewohvobdsduqjiffkyylodo
oukwwefroyamapmlrrpvdolop
cqkfxtlksjvtmtrsbycmqrrri
kfervlqidqaxaoanfqjlmcpjh
yoyywrbpfcjlfbcbbcoecspwl
twbxetyuyufvvmauawjmbwlqh
txokdexmdbtgvhpsvsqtmljdx
dcatenrehteoxqdgeueljtrrn
jarteqvtxejfsqddkbuhcysfq
hpdrowssapxtrxhpdxcdhicon
```

Comment: What is the grid in your text file? The above generates a grid. If you already have a grid, the above code is redundant for you.

Comment: Inside the grid.txt is a line of letters with words in them

Comment: Is the grid.txt already a word search?

Comment: @chris. Replace this line of code `for word in ["HELLO", "THERE", "AGAIN"]:` with this line `for word in open('mywordfile.txt').read().split():`.

Comment: yes it is, there are a few words in there like active, string, lap. I will add then onces i find out how to input my own grid @whackamadoodle3000